# Can't connect to local mosquitto broker with mqtt.js

Tags: vue.js, mqtt, mosquitto

I have tried connecting to a local mosquitto broker running on my laptop with mqtt.js.
I can connect with paho-mqtt with python over TLS. I exporting the client of my_mqtt.js and using it in a vue app

my_mqtt.js

```js
import * as mqtt from "precompiled-mqtt";

var options = {
    host: '192.168.1.161',
    port: 8883,
    protocolId: 'ws',
    clientId: 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)
}

// initialize the MQTT client
const client = mqtt.connect("ws://192.168.1.161:8883", options);

// setup the callbacks
client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
});

client.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // called each time a message is received
    console.log('Received message:', topic, message.toString());
});

// subscribe to topic 'my/test/topic'
client.subscribe('my/test/topic');

// publish message 'Hello' to topic 'my/test/topic'
client.publish('my/test/topic', 'Hello');

export default client;
```

mosquitto.conf

```
listener 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 8883
protocol websockets 

allow_anonymous true
```

```
COODER@COODER ~ % /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf -v
1667327393: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1667327393: Config loaded from /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1667327393: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1667327393: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1667327393: Opening websockets listen socket on port 8883.
1667327393: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
1667327404: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327405: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327406: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327408: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327409: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327410: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327411: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327413: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327414: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327415: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327416: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327417: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327419: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327420: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327421: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1667327422: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
```

The terminal where I am running the mosquitto broker gives the above output.

Comment: You have not configured any certificates for the websockets connection so it will not work with `wss://` only `ws://`

Comment: Updated my post. With the output from trying that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`protocolId` should never be anything other than `MQTT`

Once you remove that, everything else in the `options` object is defaults or included in the URI you are already passing to the `connect` method so you can just replace it with `{}`